# How to list all elements of an array of object in a table using ngFor directive in angular?

Tags: angular

I have to display an array of objects data into a table.

I have tried this code:

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let item of fetchedMails">
      <td><input name="name" [(ngModel)]="item.full_name"></td>
      <td><input name="email" [(ngModel)]="item.email"></td>
    </tr>
```

Where fetchedMails is the array of objects

I have used 2-way binding so that the user could able to edit the name and re-submit the form.

But in the table, I could only get the last element of the array repeated n times.

How can I display every array element in the table?

Comment: Remove the name attribute from input element or use `name="{{'name_'+i}}" and name="{{'email_'+i}}" instead.

Comment: Show `fetchedMails`

Comment: @Sanoj_V the name attribute is required for ngModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below solution.. Just remove `name` Attribute and replace it with `ngModelOptions`

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of fetchedMails">
  <td><input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="item.full_name"></td>
  <td><input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="item.email"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind index to name attribute to make name unique

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of fetchedMails; let i=index">
  <td><input name="name_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.full_name"></td>
  <td><input name="email_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.email"></td>
</tr>
```